# Enviar Email Configurado

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Gostaria de colocar na minha aplicação, o envio de e-mail. Porém gostaria que ele fosse todo configurado, que o usuário pudesse fazer as configurações, antes do envio do e-mail. Por Exemplo: colocar em itálico, negrito, mudar a cor do texto, e etc. Até o momento não localizei nenhum exemplo concreto na internet, sei como posso enviar e-mail, porém não sei como realizar esta configuração.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628683/how-to-send-html-formatted-email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você já tem a função para enviar o e-mail e nesta função existe o campo de mensagem correto?!

o que você precisa fazer é dizer que o e-mail é um html.

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Depois você precisa passar a mensagem para envio já configurada com as tags html, ficando desta forma:

```
<b>Meu nome é Fulano</b>
<br/><br/>
Enviei uma mensagem de teste...
```

Quando você enviar isto pela sua função, o provedor de e-mail vai transformar as tags da mensagem em estilo e você terá o resultado final desejado.
Se você estiver pegando o texto que seu usuário está digitando em um textarea por ex, você pode usar este plugin: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Rich-Text-Editor-WYSIWYG-Editor-in-ASPNet-MVC-5.aspx ele já possui os estilos e quando você passar por parâmetro para sua função, a mensagem vai com as tags já implementadas.

Comment: Entendi Thiago, vou pesquisar editores para webforms, e ver se consigo adaptar no meu projeto. A parte de email já está funcionando. Obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado Thiago, fiz por base no que me auxiliou e funcionou.